# How to Change/update grails view (gsp) from service class

Tags: grails, service, gsp

I have a Grails Application, which has a self implemented chat system. Now I am trying to refresh the sit ( or the box containing the messages in particular), as soon as a new Message arrived. So far I figured out three methods:

- Poll from DB every second (every incoming message is saved to DB), which would be the easiest, but create a lot of unneccessary DB usage
- Update the view from within the Messagelistener. I dunno how to do this though, what I am looking for is kind of the remoteFunction-tag as a function to call from within a service.
- Update the view from domain class via beforeInsert-event. This is my least favourite option, plus I don't know how to do it for the same reasons as option 2.

If someone has a better option or a way to realize one of mine I would be very thankful :)

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push

Comment: Also, you can try something like Gwt or Vaadin

Answer (score 0):

try http://vertx.io/ out. It's easy to setup and should do just fine for asynch-messaging